# Can i delete or stop s3 endpoint after linking it to custom domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

guys I made a static website on s3 and I redirect the s3 endpoint URL to a custom domain name which is in Aws I just wanted to ask if there is a possibility to stop or delete the s3 endpoint url but not on the custom domain name. I don't want to stream my static website, on both s3 endpoint and custom domain name

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "browsing with a custom domain name"? What do you mean by "stop the S3 Endpoint URL"? Please Edit your question to provide a lot more detail about what your configuration, what you are attempting to accomplish, what you have tried and what problems you are facing. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for replying and sorry I am new to this I just edited my question hope it's now clear to you thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot 'stop' the S3 Website Endpoint because it is used by Route 53 and Amazon S3.

Route 53 treats the entry like a `CNAME` record, resolving the Website Endpoint to direct users to the S3 bucket.